# How to create a global variable and use it in other pages?

Tags: php

I tried this :

in page1.php :

```
$GLOBALS['nb_ajout_client'] = "rrrr";
```

in page2.php :

```
$GLOBALS['nb_ajout_client'] .= " kkkkk";
```

I displayed the value of `$GLOBALS['nb_ajout_client']` but it is  kkkkk.

So how to create a `global` variable and use it anywhere ?

Comment: You include the first file into the second one right, *right* ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean you want to use the variable in another http request, if that is the case then you should look into understanding how the whole process works and why this is not possible without using a persistence layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$GLOBALS are global in all scopes throughout a script.

To pass the value to another page:

- use $_POST
- use Session (server-side )
- use cookies(client-side)

Answer (score 3):

Global variables only survive the lifetime of the program execution.

Each time you load a (PHP) page, you run a program from scratch. If you load a different page then you run a different program.

If you want to store data between them then you need to actually store it somewhere and then read it back from there in the other program.

If you want to do this globally, then the usual approach is to use a [database](http://www.sitepoint.com/re-introducing-pdo-the-right-way-to-access-databases-in-php/).

If you want to do this on a per-user basis, then the usual approach is to use a [session](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/).

You could also pass the data via the browser (e.g. by putting it in the query string of a link and then reading it back from `$_GET`).

Answer (score 1):

A variable is only 'global' in the current script. If you want to use a variable from page1, you need to `include` it from page2.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables to other page (other request) use [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

g1.php

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['nb_ajout_client'] = "rrrr";
```

g2.php

```
<?php
include('g1.php');
$GLOBALS['nb_ajout_client'] .= " kkkkk";
var_dump($GLOBALS['nb_ajout_client']);
```